# How to use StringRegExp with multi-line text?

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit, multiline

I was trying to use [`StringRegExp()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm) to match multi-line text, but no success so far.

```
$sHTML = "Keyword[wellwellwell
bla bla

bla bla bla

bla bla 

<h1> bla bla </h1>
=NeedRegExp-123123123asd endline

Keyword[wellwellwell"
 $array = StringRegExp($sHTML, 'Keyword(.*?)NeedRegExp(.*?)endline ', 1)
 For $i = 0 To UBound($array) - 1
 MsgBox(0, "RegExp Test with Option 2 - " & $i, $array[$i])
  Next
```

What I expect to get in array: `-123123123asd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the DOTALL flag. As far as I can tell from documentation, you have to use the regex flag for this as the StringRegExp function doesn't support patternwide flags?

The DOTALL flag enables `.` to match newline characters, and can be activated for the remainder of the regex by including `(?s)` in most flavors.

```
 $array = StringRegExp($sHTML, '(?s)Keyword.*?NeedRegExp(.*?)endline ', 1)
```